# jquery sortable/draggable double event firing

Tags: jquery, double, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have some drag & drop code which works fine as it is. Just have a little query. I've noticed that if I add an alert within the drop function for debugging purposes (eg. alert(draggedItem.text());) it fires the alert twice when I drop something into the draggable area. I've read in another post that using droppable & sortable together causes this weird double event to happen. But I need to use the droppable event to get the dragged item object (ui.draggable) - this is so I can manipulate it when I drop it. If there is any other way of getting the draggable object, please tell me :) Also if you have an explanation to why this happens, that would be interesting...

```
$(".field > li").draggable({
    helper:'clone',
    opacity: 0.4,
    connectToSortable:'.dragrow'
});

$(".dragrow").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        draggedItem = ui.draggable;
        //alert(draggedItem.text());
    }
}).sortable({ //code here to do stuff with 'draggedItem'
```

I also have another query related to this, but as my code is quite large, I'm unable to post the full thing here. So I understand if you are unable to help - just if something springs to mind that would be really cool. Basically I have a list of 'blocks' which I can drag into multiple rows. Individual rows can be hidden with the toggle event. If I have 3 rows, I can drag blocks into any of them. If I then hide the first one, I am now unable to drag into the other two rows. I can still sort them though. And once I start sorting them, I am then able to drag into them again. Weird...

Answer (score 3):

Check the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/FUyTe/1/

As you mentioned, yes, using droppable & sortable together causes this weird double event to happen. But, if you still want to use `draggedItem object`, you still can use this with sortable receive option.

And also, you can use `ui.item` to get the current dragged element.

#### Try to comment on and off each alert and see, now it fires only once.

```
$(".field > li").draggable({
    helper:'clone',
    opacity: 0.4,
    connectToSortable:'.dragrow'
});

$(".dragrow").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        draggedItem = ui.draggable;
    }
}).sortable({ 
    receive: function(e, ui) {
        // here is the draggedItem object of "droppable"
        alert(draggedItem.text());

        // here is the draggedItem object of "sortable"
        draggedItem2 = ui.item;
        //alert(draggedItem2.text());
    }
});
```

#### Here is one way to modify dropped element's html.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/7fEQs/8/

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked that you don't have your jquery script tag twice on your site?

Comment: Yes I have. Actually found this old post where someone came up with a solution that I never followed up (must have been distracted with another project at the time!) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095691/jquery-manipulate-dropped-element-in-sortable-list

So what I still can't figure out is why toggling droppable areas disables other droppable areas...